# Display CiviCRM Admin Menu in Drupal

Tags: admin, menu

Is there any way we can display CiviCRM Admin Menu in Drupal context ? like on any view page we want both drupal and civicrm menus.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can do this by enabling the [CiviMenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/civimenu) drupal module:

> [CiviMenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/civimenu) allows you to display the CiviCRM menubar on non-civicrm pages of your website.
>
> This module provides an invisible Drupal Block which loads the CiviCRM menubar. By default the block will display the menubar on every non-civicrm page of your website. Simply edit the block to refine exactly which pages the menubar appears on and which users have permission to see it.
>
> Note that nothing displays in the block (the menubar will always be at the top of the screen), so it doesn't matter which region of the page you add it to.

Comment: Cool - learned something!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks guys :) It's  not working  for me,  so added issue and patch here https://www.drupal.org/node/2742423. can you share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need too many items - you can put them in the Drupal Toolbar - Shortcuts! You can also install Shortcuts by Role - and then give users with different roles different buttons in their Drupal Toolbar.